# Is a simple 50 item list enough to justify using a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

In the Google I/O 2010 talk about ListView they say you might not need to use a ListView with a bounded and reasonable number of rows. They state if you are dealing with a reasonable number of rows it is possible to just lay them out in a ScrollView.

I'm curious what people find "reasonble length" means in practice.

Would a list of 50 items with each row's views just having a few strings be reasonable to layout without using a ListView? How about 12?

I'm used to using UITableViews on iPhone for most UI so I'm inclined to use ListViews on Android but I also want to be aware it might be overkill for some scenarios and I have a really limited understanding of perf on android presently.

Comment: Sorry for the pretty subjective question. It was presented in a very ambigious way in referenced video. All of these responses were a big help. I'm just moving forward with ListViews since the adapter classes seem quick to impliment. Thank you for the insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListView is really the best option for anything over 3 items, it is a good option for even 2 or 3 items. If not you'll end up writing a bunch of code that converts indexes to individual variables instead of arrays, database rows, or other data structure.

Answer (score 2):

It's not only about the number of items but also about whether or not your data collection will be dynamically updated. If you know you will never update the list while it's on screen and it doesn't have many items then a LinearLayout will do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

> In the Google I/O 2010 talk about ListView they say you might not need to use a ListView with a bounded and reasonable number of rows. They state if you are dealing with a reasonable number of rows it is possible to just lay them out in a ScrollView.

Hmmm, I can understand the logic up to a point but in reality using a `ListActivity`, for example, as your base class makes things very simple. OK, if you have a static list of only a dozen or so lines of text (one for each list 'item') then using a `ScrollView` containing `TextViews` would be an alternative but in reality using the adapter approach to `ListViews` is a lot more flexible in my opinion.

> Would a list of 50 items with each row's views just having a few strings be reasonable to layout without using a ListView? How about 12?

No, if each list item has a few strings to be laid out then custom list item layouts together with a `ListView` and a custom adapter are basically a must.

Comment: Even if each list item has a few strings to be laid out, it doesn't necessarily justify using a ListView (as long as you have only a few.)

Comment: @Romain: I actually think the question is slightly subjective and open for discussion and was in two minds about a vote to  close. Your comment "...doesn't necessarily justify..." goes further to support the subjectivity of the question. My answer was based on the OP's admission of limited understanding and in my opinion using a Listview is a good way to start. Again, subjectively, the OP doesn't specify the source of the data and, subjectivly, I'd probably use an XML or SQLite source making a ListView with an adapter trivial to implement. Whether or not it justifies things is open to debate.